DRV8262 not working with PWM signal
I designed a motor driver with the new Texas Instruments DRV8262 at its core. It will be used in robots controlled by an ESP32.
It works well when using non-PWM signals to switch the outputs in PWM mode, but as soon as I use a PWM signal it won't work anymore. I tried different frequencies from 50 Hz all the way to 150 kHz, but nothing worked. The only thing I could notice was the current draw of the whole system increasing from ~210 mA to ~230 mA. The driver didn't get warm at all and the nFault pin was at 3.3 V, which is the default state.
The schematic isn't my finest work, but I hope it works. 
What can I do to make the driver respond to PWM signals?

Datasheet: DRV8262
I hope I provided all the information needed.

please add a focused, answerable question to your post

It looks like you have MODE2 grounded- I think that changes the function of IN from PWM to PH/EN.  Double check the datasheet.

@JohnD sorry, should've clarified. I put 0-Ohm resistors there for me to be able to change modes. I first tried PH/EN mode, which didn't work with PWM and then removed the resistor for it to go into PWM mode.

Please add a link (in your question) to the data sheet

Where does the VCC supply come from? A capacitor is missing at VCC. What do you mean with "nothing worked"?

@Jens The VCC supply comes from the PCB this component is put onto. It is powered by 3.3V with a capacitor next to it, so that shouldn't be the problem. With "nothing worked" I meant that no frequency worked, so nothing between 50 Hz and 150 kHz worked.
